# GROUP_CONCAT according to values of other fields of grouped rows

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, group-concat, gaps-and-islands

I have a table with columns as bellow:

```
| id | name  | entrance | eName  |
|----|-------|----------|--------|
| 1  | user1 | 5:10     | enter1 |
| 2  | user2 | 2:15     | enter1 |
| 3  | user3 | 3:05     | enter3 |
| 1  | user1 | 5:12     | enter2 |
| 1  | user1 | 7:30     | enter2 |
```

what I try to do, is to grouping `eName` according to different of values of `entrance` field, if different between value is (2) then grouping them elsewhere return it as new row?

The desired output is as bellow:

```
| id | name  |
|----|-------|--------       |
| 1  | user1 | enter1, enter2|
| 2  | user2 | enter1        |
| 3  | user3 | enter3        |
| 1  | user1 | enter2        |
```

Comment: By '2', do you mean '2 minutes' ?

Comment: @Strawberry yes that is what I meant.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GROUP\_CONCAT according to values of other fields of grouped rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64659044/group-concat-according-to-values-of-other-fields-of-grouped-rows)

Comment: Are you sure? Is 7.30 '7 hours and 30 minutes' or '7 minutes and 30 seconds'?

Comment: @Strawberry '7 hours and 30 minutes'

Comment: @P.Salmon yes, both of them.

Comment: Ok. Can we see what you have tried?

Comment: What if `user1` has a record at `5:14`, would you group it with the two others, or not?

Comment: @Strawberry I tried many solution but I don't know how to compare values of fields in group_contact

Comment: @GMB if user2 have records at 2:13 or 2:17 will grouped with other values elsewhere it will be another row.

Comment: Here's a clue: start with a join

Comment: @Strawberry can u write entire  statment.

Answer (score 1):

I read this as a gaps-and-islands problem, where islands are made of adjacent entrances of the same user with a gap of 2 minutes maximum.

Here is an approach using window functions (available in MySQL 8.0):

```
select id, name, group_concat(ename order by entrance) enames, 
    count(*) cnt_entrances, min(entrance) first_entrance, max(entrance) last_entrance
from (
    select t.*,
        sum(entrance > lag_entrance + interval 2 minute) over(partition by id, name order by entrance) grp
    from (
        select t.*, 
            lag(entrance, 1, entrance) over(partition by id, name order by entrance) lag_entrance
        from mytable t
    ) t
) t
group by id, name, grp
```

`lag()` gives you the date of the "previous" entrance, then we use a cumulative `sum()` that increments every time a gaps of more than 2 minutes is met to define the groups. I added a few more columns to the resultset to make it more understandable.

**[Demo on DB Fiddlde](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=34b4965452a27f220a8ca4d4ee90acb9)**:

```
id | name  | enames        | cnt_entrances | first_entrance | last_entrance
-: | :---- | :------------ | ------------: | :------------- | :------------
 1 | user1 | enter1,enter2 |             2 | 05:10:00       | 05:12:00     
 1 | user1 | enter2        |             1 | 07:30:00       | 07:30:00     
 2 | user2 | enter1        |             1 | 02:15:00       | 02:15:00     
 3 | user3 | enter3        |             1 | 03:05:00       | 03:05:00
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but my SQL version is not MySQL 8.0, so that isn't worked, are there any way to get same result with older version?

Comment: @AliAlaoi: solving such problem is challenging in MySQL < 8.0, because window functions are not available. Any plans to upgrade?